# How does $x^2-8x+17=0$ have nonreal solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The solutions of $x^2-8x+17=0$ are $4 + i$ and $4 - i$.

Well, I calculated and the results are different.

$$\begin{align}
x^2-8x+17 &= 0 \\
x^2-8x &=17 \\
x(x-8) &= 17 
\end{align}$$

So the roots are $x=17$ or $x=17+8=25$.

Why $i$ comes from the problem? Could you please explain about it?

Comment: You got $x(x-8)=17$. How on earth does $x=17$ or $x=25$ come from that?

Comment: You may deduce that $x=17$ or $x=17+8=25$ from $x(x-8)=17$ only if you assume $x$ is a positive integer; this is not necessarily true.

Comment: Your calculations are extremely mistaken. I advise you do a careful reviewing of your procedures.

Comment: You complete the square, just as one always does for quadratic equations.

Comment: $x^2-8x+17=0\implies x(x-8)=-17$

Comment: Then, I would like to know how $i$ comes from $x(x-8)=-17$. Enlighten me please. @AnginaSeng

Comment: @ToreBos Complete the square!

Comment: It's true that $ab=0$ if and only if $a=0$ or $b=0$. But it's **not** true that $ab=17$ if and only if $a=17$ or $b=17$, as you seem to believe.

Comment: @Kenta S: no, you may not make that deduction, whether or not you assume x is a positive integer.

Comment: Oh... BTW  $x^2 - 8x + 17 = 0$ would mean $x^2 - 8x = -17 \ne 17$.

Comment: @KentaS  $x(x-2) = 15; x \in \mathbb N$.  Then .... we can't assume $x =15$ or $x-2=15$ *UNLESS* we *also* assum $x-2 =1$ or $x = 1$.  but $15-2\ne 1$ and $1-2 \ne 15$ so we can't assume that and $x=15$ or $x = 17$ are *NOT* solutions.  But $x=5$ is.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, but $17$ is prime and $15$ isn't.

Comment: @KentaS but you didn't say we can only assume that if $x$ is natural and then integer is a prime.  You said we can only assume that if $x$ is natural.  And even if we assume $x$ is natural and the integer is prime, that doesn't actually *mean* there is a solution at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is not correct, please check it.

$x^{2}-8x+17=(x-4)^{2}+1=0$ by [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square), so we have $(x-4)^{2}=-1$ and thus $x=4+i$ and $x=4-i$ are the required solutions where $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your rearrangement should have given $x(x-8)=-17$. Secondly, $x(x-8)=c\implies x=c\lor x-8=c$ only works for $c=0$, because non-zero $c$ have other factorizations. The correct observation is that $(x-4)^2=x^2-8x+16=-1=i^2$, so $x-4=\pm i$.

Answer (score 2):

Here, you can use the quadratic formula:

$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

$$x=\frac{-(-8)\pm\sqrt{(-8)^2-4(1)(17)}}{2(1)}$$

$$x=\frac{8\pm\sqrt{64-68}}{2}$$

$$x=\frac{8\pm\sqrt{-4}}{2}$$

$$x=\frac{8\pm2i}{2}$$

$$x=4\pm i $$

When you are calculating, you're trying to apply the zero product property to all numbers, which doesn't work. If the equation was

$$x(x-8)=0$$

you could determine the roots from that immediately. Since it's not $0$ (it's actually $-17$ and not $17$), you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sqrt{-1}=i$$$x^2-8x+17=0 \implies x=\frac{8\pm \sqrt{64-68}}{2}=\frac{8+\sqrt{-4}}{2}=4\pm i$$
So (A) option is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you take $x = 17$ then $x^{2} - 8x + 17 = 289 - 56 + 17 = 362 \not=0$

Neither hold if you take $x = 25$

You can use Bhaskara's formula. $x = \frac{8+\sqrt{64 - 68}}{2} = 4 + i$ or $x = \frac{8-\sqrt{64 - 68}}{2} = 4 - i$

Answer (score 1):

$x(x-8)=17$ is a true (but not useful) statement.

But $ab = m$ most certainly does !**NOT**! mean $a =m$ or $b=m$.

Consider $3\cdot 5 = 15$ where neither $3=15$ nor $5 = 15$.  Or consider $\frac 2{5}\cdot {85}2 = 17$ where neither $\frac 12$ nor $\frac {85}2$ equal $17$.

In fact $x(x-8)=17$ *CAN'T* mean $x =17$ *unless* $x-8=1$.  But $17-8 \ne 9$.  And $x-8$ *CAN'T* equal $17$ unless $x =1$ and $1-8 \ne 17$.

So your solution is definitely wrong.

We could true $x = \frac {17}{x-8}$ and $x-8 = \frac {17}x$ neither of which are equal to $1$ or $17$ but .... that doesn't get us anywhere.  (Also this assumes $x, x-8$ are neither $0$... which we *can* assume because if either were $0$ their product would have to be $0$ and *not* $17$.)

.....

We *can't* to $ab=m$ means $a=m$ or $b=m$ because that's just garbage.

But we can do $ab = 0$ means $a=0$ or $b=0$.  Why does this work for $0$ and not for $m$?

Because $0\cdot anything = 0$ always happens while $m \cdot x = m$ *doesn't* always happen. And because $ab=m$ where $a\ne m; b\ne m$ *can* happen $ab = 0$ where $a\ne 0; b\ne 0$ can *NOT* happen.

....

So we could solve this by factoring $x^2 -8x + 17$ to $(x+a)(x+b)$ and having $(x+a)(x+b) = 0$. so $x+a =0$ or $x+b = 0$.

The only trouble is .... we don't know how to factor $x^2 - 8x + 17$......

But we can complete the square.   If we have $x(x-8) = 17$ we can say anything about $x$ or $x-8$.  But if *instead* we had $(x+a)(x+a) = M$ where $x+a$ and $x+a$ are the *same* things and not *different* things. the we can conclude if $(x+a)^2 = M$ then $x+a = \pm \sqrt M$.

And we can find an $x^2 -8x + something\ that\ isn't\ 17$ is a perfect square so we can do

$x^2 - 8x + 17 =0$

$x^2 - 8x= -17$

$x^2 - 8x +something\ that\ isn't\ 17\ but\ which \makes\ this \side\ a\ perfect\ square = -17 ++something\ that\ isn't\ 17\ but\ which \makes\ this \side\ a\ perfect\ square$

So what *is* $something\ that\ isn't\ 17\ but\ which \makes\ this \side\ a\ perfect\ square$?

If $x^2 - 8x +something\ that\ isn't\ 17\ but\ which \makes\ this \side\ a\ perfect\ square = (x+ \ who \ knows)^2$ then

$x^2 - 8x +something\ that\ isn't\ 17\ but\ which \makes\ this \side\ a\ perfect\ square = x^2 + 2\ who \ knows\ x + \ who\ know^2$.

So $-8x = 2\ who\ knows\ x$ so $\ who\ knows = \frac {-8}2 = -4$.

And $something\ that\ isn't\ 17\ but\ which \makes\ this \side\ a\ perfect\ square = \ who\ know^2= (-4)^2 = 16$.

.....

SO.....

$x^2 -8x + 17 = 0$

$x^2 - 8x = -17$

$x^2 - 8x + 16 = -17 +16$

$(x-4)^2 = -1$.

Now that means $x-4 = \pm \sqrt{-1}$.

> AND $\sqrt{-1} = i$!  THAT IS WHERE THE $i$ CAME FROM!

And so $x - 4 =\pm i$

And $x = 4 \pm i$.  So $x = 4+i$ or $x = 4-i$.

Answer (score 1):

Also note:

If the solutions are $a, b$ then $(x-a)(x-b) = 0$ and $x^2 -(a+b)x + ab = 0$ and as $x^2 - 8x +17 =0$ we would have $a+b = 8$ and $ab = 17$.

Option 1:  $4 + i$ and $4- i$.  Then $(4+i) + (4-i) = (4+4) + (i-i) = 8$.  So for so good.  $(4-i)(4+i) = 16 + 4i - 4i -i^2 = 16 -i^2 = 16 -(-1) =16+1 = 17$.  That works.

Option 2: $-8, 17$.  Then $-8 + 17 =9 \ne 8$ so no good.  ANd $(-8)\cdot 17=-onehundredsomethingbig \ne 17$.  Really no good.

Option 3: $4$ and $-4$.  Then $4+ (-4) = 0\ne 8$.  No good.  And $4\times (-4) = -16 \ne 17$. No good.

Option 4: $\sqrt{17},-\sqrt{17}$.  Then $\sqrt{17}+(-\sqrt{17}) = 0\ne 8$.  And $\sqrt{17}\cdot (-\sqrt{17}) = -17\ne 17$.  So no good.